# My mistake, or bug in intel compiler? sizeof a non-static member error

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof

It is my belief that this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    char array[1024];
};

int main() { 
    fprintf(stderr, "sizeof(foo::array): %zd\n", sizeof(foo::array));    
}
```

Is valid C++.  g++ compiles it just fine with -ansi -pedantic.  However, compiling with Intel's icc 12.1.3 I get:

```
error #288: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
```

Is it my mistake or is icc doing the wrong thing re: the C++ spec?

Comment: This is [N2253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2253.html), part of C++11.

Comment: clang++ thinks it's an error too: `<stdin>:8:62: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'array'
    fprintf(stderr, "sizeof(foo::array): %zd\n", sizeof(foo::array));    
                                                        ~~~~~^~~~~
`

Comment: GCC defaults to C++11 now, maybe that's the issue?  You'll probably need to tell other compilers to use C++11, possibly with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @PaulR: Works on clang with C++11 too [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cdc52a939a9cd69).

Comment: @Tavian, I'm using gcc 4.4.7, so no c++11 support yet.

Comment: @gct You can see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) that N2253 was implemented in GCC 4.4.  They may have implemented it for C++98/03 too.

Comment: What is the version of your compiler? The [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler) states that N2253 is supported from ICC v14.0

Comment: @PaulR [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45a7fbb0b97e1f64).

Comment: @BaummitAugen: yes, it's fine with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` - it just depends on what your compiler default is. See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd19f60ba3bb0098

Comment: Intel compiler 16.0 (build 20150815) for Windows compiles the code without any problem in both c++98 and c++11 modes.

Comment: You can easily work around the problem with `sizeof(foo().array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a compiler bug or maybe the compiler was issued before this feature was adopted in the Standard.

According to the C++ Standard (5.1 Primary expressions)

> 13 An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or
>   non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> — if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it
>   appears in an unevaluated operand.

```
[ Example:
struct S {
int m;
};
int i = sizeof(S::m); // OK
int j = sizeof(S::m + 42); // OK
—end example ]
```

Comment: It's sounding like gcc back-ported the feature into C++98, and it wasn't added in icc until 14.0

Comment: @gct It sounds correctly. The C+= Standard allows to use such a construction. All other is your personal problem.

Comment: @gct Also read comments where there is given a reference to N2253